# Weird issue with slider on javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page that i am using revolution slider on the page and everything works fine. I have a global javascript that runs on each page that looks at the url variables on the page, city and tel and then changes the page based on that. Now the issue is very weird and i can't figure out where to even start troubleshooting it

If i go to this url:

```
http://www.test.com?city=boston
```

Page works perfect and no issues

If it go to this url:

```
http://www.test.com?city=boston&number=5555555555
```

Then the slider stops working, its almost like it doesn't like that i have 2 url variables which is very weird.

I thought it could have been issue with a reserved word or something, i but i tried different words and even random words and nothing it always happens when i urs 2 url vars.

Can anyone please assist me with this?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Development Stack Exchange! Please note that questions regarding 3rd Party Plugins such as Revolution Slider are [Off-Topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This doesn't *sound* like an issue inherent to WordPress but Revolution Slider itself. I would contact the plugin developers and see if they can solve the issue as most likely it would be in the plugins code which any updates you make to it will be overridden on update.